# Can ZipFile on Android handle archives larger than 2 GB?

Tags: android, zip

I'm running into the following `ZipException` trying to open a ~2.8GB zip using `java.util.zip.ZipFile` on Android.

```
2020-06-08 11:40:23.207 E/WM-WorkerWrapper: Work [ id=a9215267-a591-4589-8c40-24fab8c4abc4, tags={ com.visualdx.android.remote.worker.ExtractDataWorker, install } ] failed because it threw an exception/error
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:516)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:298)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:265)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:187)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:201)
```

Due to the error message, I've checked the signature on the zip file and that appears to be valid based on [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

```
❯ hexdump -n 4 ~/Downloads/data.zip 
0000000 50 4b 03 04                                    
0000004
```

I've been successful opening zip files using `java.util.zip.ZipFile` for other zips up to 500MB in length without issue, so my only guess is that file size is the problem, but I can't seem to find a limit documented anywhere. Does anyone have any ideas about what could be wrong here?

Also, if it's relevant, this is an app targeting API 29 with a min SDK version of 23.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Android supported individual files that large, whether ZIP or otherwise.

Comment: It does. In fact, using the apache commons compress library, I've been able to open this zip and read entries from it without issue. It's just not an ideal solution because it tends to be slower to index entries than the native `java.util.zip.ZipFIle` implementation on Android.